# Position fixed breaks in Chrome, works in FF

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, user-interface

The top bar on my [Site](http://www.topforty.it) has fixed positioning. It works great on Firefox 7 but breaks in the latest Chrome. I can't figure out why. The element that I am talking about has an id of "top-wrapper"

Comment: Looks fine to me. Could we see screenshots both FF and Chrome?

Comment: the body style `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` seems to be causing the problem. At least, disabling it resolves the problem. What are you using that for? [Demo, try adding and removing that CSS property here](http://jsbin.com/ininec/edit#html,live). Also, whenever you use a `-webkit` style, that explains the difference between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I'm having this problem when I set -webkit-perspective on the body

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because you set `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);` on body element.

So you just need to remove this.

Comment: Do you also have a proposed solution? Otherwise, this should probably be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Do Tilo Mitra asked a question? No he just wrote about one of his problems. So I just wrote down what the problem is.
(I mean I thought peoples would expect nothing more)

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I agree. It seems reasonable to assume that OP's question is about how to get the `position: fixed` behaviour working, but I'm not sure it's as reasonable to assume that we can safely help him by telling him to remove `-webkit-transform`. Do we know why it's there in the first place? If it serves a useful purpose, can we somehow replace it with something that doesn't have the side-effect of breaking positioning, or can we perchance remove it from body and delegate it to some container of which `#top-wrapper` is not a child?

Comment: @DavidHedlund the css3 key is just for **chrome** (so it won't work in firefox) and the value (`translateZ(0)`) is usually used at 3d elements. And I can't see anything on the page which needs this and if there would be something, something won't work in firefox.

Comment: That is there to allow animations to use Hardware Acceleration but I should be able to take that attribute out from <body> and put it in a more granular level.

Edit: I'll make the change and confirm back here.

Comment: This fixes the issue. The "-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);" has been moved to the parent of the elements which are being transformed using CSS animations. This was just done for performance for iOS. Thanks for the help, all.