# fixed position + draggable in Webkit

Tags: jquery, draggable, css-position

i have a strange issue with my draggable div container.

I try to make a Div with text draggable and want the headline of each div sticky. 
In Firefox all works perfect but in Chrome(webkit..) it doesnt :(

my code for the draggable functionality is

```
$content.children().draggable({
    axis: "y",
    snap: true,
    distance: 20,
    start: function(e,ui){
        //...
    },
    drag: function(e) {

        $('.sc_conSticky').each(function(index) {
            var $this = $(this),           // h1.headerSticky
                $wrap = $this.parent(),    // .textwrapper
                $win = $(window);          //window


                var wrapPos = $wrap.offset().top, 
                    elemSize = $this.outerHeight(),
                    wrapSize = $wrap.outerHeight(),
                    scrollPos = 0;    //$win.scrollTop(); always 0 o.O

                if (    scrollPos >= wrapPos  &&
                    (wrapSize + wrapPos) >= (scrollPos + elemSize)) {
                    $this.css({
                        position: 'fixed',
                        top: 0
                    });
                } else if (scrollPos < wrapPos) {
                    $this.css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: 0
                    });
                } else {
                    $this.css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: wrapSize - elemSize
                    });
                }
        });

    },
    stop: function(e,ui) {
        //...
});
```

My HTML structure looks like this

```
<div class="textwrapper">
   <h1 class="sc_conSticky">  </h1>
  text text text .... 
</div>
<div class="textwrapper">
   <h1 class="sc_conSticky">  </h1>
  text text text .... 
</div>
```

In the picture you can show the problem. The first browser is chrome and the second is firefox.

[image: error with chrome and fixed position + draggable]

Does someone know where the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

hansinger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! :)  it was due a bug of Chrome.

you can not use "-webkit-transform" together with position fixed in webkit Browser.

for further information, show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8151075/position-fixed-breaks-in-chrome-works-in-ff)